# How do you pronounce "grimace"?

Tags: nouns, pronunciation

How do you pronounce *grimace*? My parents taught me a long time ago to say "gri-MACE". Then the Burger King character Gri... came along.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Any dictionary will provide the common pronunciations of a word; online dictionaries will include [sound clips](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/grimace).

Comment: **ON HOLD**? My attempt to answer the question using the good old 'commonly-available references' has met with contradictory rulings!

Comment: Who do you want to offend, McDonalds or your parents?

Comment: Grimace is a fat overlord.  How did he get all those burgers?  He has Hamburglar swipe them and he sits on his fat purple ass eating them like cookies.  McDonald's using the drug ring metaphor is perfect.  How do I pronounce Grimace?  With resentment and jealousy and a slight grimace on my face.

Answer (score 1):

Grimmis - with the stress on the first syllable.

Grimace is that purple character from McDonald's. I first heard this word from old McDonald's commercials, and it was pronounced "grimmis".

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation has changed.

English nouns have a tendency to be stressed on the first syllable, and verbs on later syllables. In my experience, the word is almost always stressed on the first syllable in American English, at least in the Northeast. However, the [1892 Webster's International Dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=qL8WAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=webster%27s+international+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=amJzU-jPCMeeyAT2w4CwAg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=grim&f=false) puts the stress on the second syllable, so presumably that was the preferred American 19th century pronunciation then (I assume the same was true in the U.K.). The stress has shifted forward since then, as commonly happens for English second-syllable-stressed nouns.

It appears that the stress was already changing in 1888, before the above dictionary was published. Warren's [*Practical Ortheopy and Critique*](http://books.google.com/books?id=jqULAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA227&dq=%22grim-ace%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UIBzU9a6HevKsQTl2oLACw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22grim-ace%22&f=false) includes the advice "gri-**mace**, not **grim**-ace".

What is surprising to me is that the stress also shifted forward for the verb. My guess at the reason behind this is that the noun was much more common than the verb when the stress shifted, and the shift in the noun stress carried the verb stress with it in this case. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grimace%2C+grimaced&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrimace%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrimaced%3B%2Cc0) shows that the noun form was indeed much more common at the turn of the century (although the verb form is more common now).

So you can confidently continue pronouncing *grimace* with the stress on the second syllable. Even if people think you are pronouncing it wrong, you have the consolation of knowing that you are being historically accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the upper midwest US I say it *GRIMM-ess* or *GRIMM-uss*.

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford English Dictionary has only the second-syllable accent.  The New Oxford American Dictionary has both, with the first-syllable accent listed first.  I am guessing this is a UK/US difference.

Comment: I don't think so; I'm amazed that the OED lists them in the order you say. I'm used to a schwa for the second syllable. [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/grimace#) lists this as the only option.

Comment: Interesting ... Oxford /ɡrɪˈmeɪs/ and Cambridge /ˈɡrɪ.məs/

Comment: Better look up an Ngram of the Boat Race.

Comment: It definitely seems like a US-UK thing to me; I don't believe I have ever heard it pronouced gri-MACE in the US.

Answer (score -1):

I usually say "grim-US", although according to dictionary.com "grim-MACE" is also a common pronunciation.